# Why is Tomcat manager using my LoginModule?

Tags: security, tomcat, tomcat6, jaas

I'm running Tomcat 6.0.29 and created a realm and loginmodule of my own.  They are defined in server.xml like so:

`<Realm className="mycompany.tomcat.MyRepositoryRealm"
appName="My_Realm"
userClassNames="mycompany.tomcat.IdentityPrincipal"
roleClassNames="mycompany.tomcat.RolePrincipal"
useContextClassLoader="true"/>`

I have added the library containing these classes to my tomcat/lib folder.  Other than that, I have not changed Tomcat from it's default configuration.

When I go to fire up the Tomcat manager application at `http://localhost:9080/manager/html`, I can't log in and the tomcat log shows an error and stacktrace for my login module.

Any ideas? Thanks!

**Edit:**

Per request, here is the stacktrace.  My realm connects to a JBoss service, so that's why I get the NamingContextFactory error.

`javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Cannot instantiate class: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
    at mycompany.tomcat.MyRepositoryLoginModule.login(MyRepositoryLoginModule.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:769)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:186)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:579)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm.authenticate(JAASRealm.java:410)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm.authenticate(JAASRealm.java:335)
    at mycompany.tomcat.MyRepositoryRealm.authenticate(MyRepositoryRealm.java:34)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator.authenticate(BasicAuthenticator.java:181)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:528)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to figure out the problem.

Security realms can be defined for an engine, host, or context.  I had defined the realm for the whole host (in server.xml), so the tomcat manager application was trying to use it.  I fixed the problem by defining the realm in a META-INF/context.xml file inside of my web application.