# How to define Tomcat security Realms per webapp

Tags: java, tomcat, jaas

When using JAAS JDBCRealms with Tomcat, I usually define the realm in `server.xml`. But now I am looking for a simpler solution, where I don't have to configure the Tomcat container when deploying the application.

If possible, I would like to keep all the JAAS configuration in web.xml and just define the realm per application/webapp.

One thread mentions that he did this by defining the realm in `META-INF/context.xml` of the webapp.. but I could not get it working ([Why is Tomcat manager using my LoginModule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859160/why-is-tomcat-manager-using-my-loginmodule/3859630#3859630=)).

Please help me find the correct location in the .war to define a `org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm` that is then used for that webapp.

Comment: Maybe I found the solution:
Only if a context file does not exist for the application in the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/, in an individual file at /META-INF/context.xml inside the application files. If the web application is packaged as a WAR then /META-INF/context.xml will be copied to $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/ and renamed to match the application's context path. Once this file exists, it will not be replaced if a new WAR with a newer /META-INF/context.xml is placed in the host's appBase.
from http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To define your own `JDBCRealm`, create a `META-INF/context.xml` **in** your own web application.

Configure your JDBCRealm according to the specification based on your Tomcat Server versions:

- [Tomcat 5.5](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/realm.html)
- [Tomcat 6.0](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html)
- [Tomcat 7.0](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html)

These links shows you exactly how to configure JDBCRealm.

Comment: Arrg! I just saw that a custom realm implementation must be accessible in CATALINA_HOME, not only from the JARs of my web app. This sucks. I don't understand the point of being able to define custom / per Webapp Realm if it has to be deployed on the whole Tomcat installation anyway.